# Dynamically change axis in UIStackView

Tags: ios, view, autolayout, uistackview

I have 2 views in a horizontal UIStackView. What I'm trying to achieve is for the stack view to stay in horizontal mode if possible, but if this isn't possible then change to a vertical mode. Demonstrated in the image below. When in the second case it can't fit horizontally it changes to vertical:
[image: Stack view]

How could this be achieved using UIStackViews and autolayout?
In a more general sense I would love to have a view that mimics CSS flex-wrap properties. I.e.:

[image: flex-wrap]

Though that seems like a far more complicated task.

Comment: Might be a good idea to consider using UICollectionViewFlowLayout with AutoSizingCells, I'm facing a similar challenge now.